# how to download a file from a link?

Tags: php, laravel, file, download

I have a link for example "https://www.example.com/example-811.jpg"
I need to upload it to laravel storage (../app/storage/public/).
This is the maximum that I could implement in the controller, everything is fine, but the files are loaded in the TMP extension, how can I load the file in the required format?

```
        $filename = 'example-811.jpg';
        $tempImage = tempnam('..\storage\app\public', $filename);
        copy('https://www.example.com/example-811.jpg', $tempImage);

        dd(response()->download($tempImage, $filename));
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` can help you

Comment: the content-type header contains normally the type of file take it from there and concat in your string

Comment: @urfusion and how to convert the code into a picture then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it can be done more conveniently, but I just removed from $ tempImage 4 characters at the end of the line

```
$expansion = substr($filename, -4);;
$tempImage = tempnam('..\storage\app\public', $filename);
$tempImage = substr($tempImage, 0, -4) . $expansion;
```

and added the extension

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to download a file:

```
$filename = 'example-811.jpg';
$path = public_path().'/storage/'.$filename;
return response()->download($path, $filename, ['Content-Type' => $filename]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on the contrary, I need to send the file